# Some SEO tools tells me that the website is redirecting to a strange url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a really strange "problem". I tryed to check my main page from the site (http://www.zen-slim.com/) with some online redirect tools and i got a strange "reaction" from them.

- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/690/55667353.jpg/
- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/52062478.jpg/
- http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/79452246.jpg/

As you could see in the pictures, on this particular tool, i receive two 302 redirects and then a 200 (which i think it should have been the normal thing, as the site is working and operational). I tryed to check the header responses with curl and fsocketopen and i got 200 responses from both of them. But the online tools say something different.
My .htaccess file is http://pastebin.com/Wgjxrq83.

Could you please help, because i really don't know what's wrong with it.

Thank you.

Comment: It may be possible that your host is redirecting the calls from the (probably known) tool via different stuff to help it with its SEO (or something like that). I'm not sure, but that might be the case. Try with a different tool and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was, finally, being able to figure this out. Aparently, the following code from .htaccess file was the problem:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [R=301,L]
```

and changed it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  zen-slim\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.zen-slim.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

This is definitely a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever software you use, your site runs a check on first request and testates and injects something with a drive-by-redirect on first request.

```
$ curl -Iv http://www.zen-slim.com/
* About to connect() to www.zen-slim.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 46.252.196.1... connected
* Connected to www.zen-slim.com (46.252.196.1) port 80 (#0)
> HEAD / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.6 (i386-pc-win32) libcurl/7.21.6 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: www.zen-slim.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0
< Location: /?9cc38870
Location: /?9cc38870

<
* Connection #0 to host www.zen-slim.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Or via http://blooming-mountain-4729.herokuapp.com/web/shorturl.php?http://www.zen-slim.com/

```
Original URL: http://www.zen-slim.com/
Resulting URL: /
Status code (after all redirects): 403
Number of responses: 3
Number of redirects: 2
 * http://www.zen-slim.com/ -- 302 --> /?07731fc0
 * /?07731fc0 -- 302 --> /
```

Afterwards it even gives you a 403 (forbidden) if the browser does not follow suite:

```
Original URL: http://www.zen-slim.com/
Resulting URL: http://www.zen-slim.com/
Status code (after all redirects): 403
Number of responses: 1
Number of redirects: 0
```

This is less a programming but more a webmaster related question I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your site with Website Auditor. It says that all your pages are 200, but for 
http://www.zen-slim.com/questionnaire, which is 302.